# Remove number delimeters with regex

Tags: php, regex, numbers

I'm looking for a *simple stupid* solution, to **remove delimiters from numbers within strings**.

This function replaces `2.000 BC` with `2000 BC`:

```
$text preg_replace("/^[0-9.]+$/", "", $text);
```

Example:

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor. Consetetur elitr 2.000 BC sed diam nonumy 300.'

// Current behaviour (the delimeter at the end ot the line disappears):
// Lorem ipsum dolor. Consetetur elitr 2000 BC sed diam nonumy 300

// Expected behaviour:
// Lorem ipsum dolor. Consetetur elitr 2000 BC sed diam nonumy 300.
```

Comment: What if there is a number like `.45`, do you want to remove dot there too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)` with nothing:

```
<?php

$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor. Consetetur elitr 2.000 BC sed diam nonumy 300.';

$text = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)/', '', $text);

var_dump($text);

//string(64) "Lorem ipsum dolor. Consetetur elitr 2000 BC sed diam nonumy 300."
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/169446)

**Regex autopsy**:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- `(?<=\d)` - *a positive lookbehind matching a digit (this will not be replaced) - essentially this requires the `.` to be preceeded by a digit*
- `\.` - *a literal `.` character, escaped as `.` means "any character" in regex*
- `(?<=\d)` - *a positive lookahead matching a digit (this will not be replaced) - essentially this requires the `.` to be followed by a digit*

Answer (score 0):

To match the delimiter present only inside a number,

```
\d+\K\.(?=\d+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sB6pV0/1)

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/UZoyqO)

Your PHP code should be,

```
<?php
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor. Consetetur elitr 2.000 BC sed diam nonumy 300.';
$pattern = "~\d+\K\.(?=\d+)~";
$replacement = "";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor. Consetetur elitr 2000 BC sed diam nonumy 300.
```

**Explanation:**

- `\d+` One or more digits.
- `\K` Discards the previously matched characters.
- `.(?=\d+)` Matches a literal dot which should be followed by one or more digits.